# Jquery each() function loop with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I wish to replace values in each div class with my ajax result but i cannot seem to append my table result to the individual div class during the loop. I know somehow the `$(this).append(table)` is placed wrongly because it is not outside of the ajax request. How can i modify this to get the effect i wanted?

my script is as such:

```
$('.developer_badgesarea').each(function(){
    // get the div class value to perform ajax
    var player_id = $(this).html();
    var table;

    // if condition to conduct ajax
    if(player_id != 'None'){

        $.ajax({
            // ajax stuff here
            success: function(result){
                //table created here
                $(this).append(table);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Noticed a missing `}` for the `if` block.

Comment: @experiment it is a html table that i have created using my result.

Comment: have you added table to DOM???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is your "this" reference inside the ajax success function. It references the callback function, instead of the dom element you are intending it to be referenced.

`$('.developer_badgesarea').each(function(){
    // element reference to your div, that you'll access inside your ajax call
    var elm = $(this);
    // get the div class value to perform ajax
    var player_id = elm.html(); 
    var table;`

```
// if condition to conduct ajax
if(player_id != 'None'){

    $.ajax({
        // ajax stuff here
        success: function(result){
            //table created here
            elm.append(table);
        }
    });
}
```

});